# Cannot draw layout when screen is off- in Oreo

Tags: android, android-service, lockscreen, android-8.0-oreo, android-windowmanager

I have implemented a call recognition app which displays a `View` that contains the caller id. More specifically it is a `Service` with a `WindowManager` where I add the `View`. I also use the *draw over other apps* permission.
The problem is only in Android 8, in case that the user enables the screen lock (Settings-> Security & Location -> Screen Lock).
In this senario if the device screen is off, and someone calls, my call recognition is not displayed. (The only thing I can see is the native call recognition app that is ringing)
My `Service` code runs correctly but the user cannot see the UI.
Do you have something in mind?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After several tries I found that the following parameter should be passed in the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` constructor.

flags -> `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED`

For earlier versions of Android although I didn't use this parameter it was ok.